# How do I stop Facebook from deleting a link in my post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

When you post something on your timeline (personal profile) that contains a link, Facebook will create a preview of the link (using the Open Graph information provided by the linked site) and put it under your post. Recently, while the link is still visible when creating/editing a post, it won't show up in the post itself.

So this post:

> Here's a link:
>   -> http://example.com

... becomes this when posted:

> Here's a link:
>   ->
>   *generated preview*

Is there any way to prevent Facebook from removing the link from my post?

**Edit:** Here are some screenshots to demonstrate this behaviour, as requested by @ale.

Here's what my post looks like when I edit it:

[image: post in editing mode]

And here's how it appears on my timeline:

[image: post in timeline]

Comment: Are you facing this problem with any specific post or all the posts with link? And after how many hours or days you noticed this change?

Comment: @serenesat This happens with all posts that contain one link. It's been like this for a few months, not sure when Facebook started doing this. Facebook hides the link immediately when posted. It is still there though, you can see it when you edit the post

Comment: Are they hiding any specific link or all the links whatever you post?

Comment: @serenesat Every post with one link. It's not like they're censoring anything, I think it's their idea of improved user experience. Is this happening for no one else?

Comment: Can you provide some screen shots? I don't see this behavior. (I always need to manually delete the link text and just leave the preview.)

Comment: @ale I have added two screenshots

Answer (score 1):

The preview is an actual link itself. The links are actually not removed when you post, it would be great if you can attach some screenshots.

To double check, I tried creating one post and checked the same in the desktop and mobile as well. Works as intended.

Comment: Yeah the preview is a link, but the clickable text-link goes away. That's what I meant, sorry if it was unclear

Comment: No, I got that. I was saying that when I tried to do it, the text didn't go away! Where are you posting from? Web or Mobile?

Comment: From Web, but posting from mobile is no solution for me anyway